# Google App Script web app cannot be opened by others

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, web-applications

I have deployed a web app using google app script. In my computer everything works fine, the app loads data from a google sheets file and presents in a table. The issue comes when I try to share the deployed link with others. I already changed permissions of the app to "Anyone", "Anyone including anonymous", execute the app always as myself and execute the app as the user and nothing seems to work. When users clic the link they only see a Google sign saying the file can't be reached. Do youy have any suggestions?

The link of my latest implementation is here:https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbwhBuYsrRVabtSm983UWYCtRQ3KRn9ATmp0r7wGFVasMWQUjpf7L6h2qUIDRA5SFEg/exec

Thanks.

Comment: Your latest implementation is not publicly accessible. In any case, it's most probable that the web app is trying to access a file to which the accessing users don't have access. You say you tried setting `execute the app always as myself`, but if you have access to this file, you shouldn't get this problem. Please consider providing a set of reproduction steps for this.

Answer (score 0):

It's very likely that you set the web app deployment to be run as the user accessing the web app but the spreadsheet is not shared with anyone on the web / anyone with the link.

To fix this change the spreadsheet sharing settings accordingly.

Please be aware that once the users access the spreadsheet through your web app they will be able to find the spreadsheet in Google Drive and in Google Sheets > Shared with me.

Comment: Hello. Is there any way to avoid this? I am affraid that anonymous or unknown users could change the google sheets. My plan is to put this webapp in a webpage where anyone could read and search the data

Comment: If your app doesn't need to do changes to the spreadsheet you might share it to view only.

Answer (score 0):

I have a same issue with you Rivaa.

What I did is:

1. https://script.google.com/home > let the others check on 'Shared With Me'
2. give ur email via Lastpass in order to avoid show your password

I hope these will help you more or less.

Comment: Hello. Could you please explain a little bit more what you did I don't understand very well :(

Comment: Oh 

1) Let the another person that you've shared with check on the left bar of https://script.google.com/ in the menu of 'Shared with Me'
2) check out this link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EnxWDNXlF7Q&ab_channel=WebsiteSoSimple

Hope this might help you Rivaa